# Redux container cannot display the reducer handling an API call

Tags: javascript, html, api, redux

I have been building a basic weather app using React, Redux, Redux-promise and Axios (handling an API for the current weather using openweathermap.org).
If the button gets clicked, the weather parameters of the city (Cecciola) should be displayed on the console.
The Action correctly retrieves the data and, thanks to Promise, it is passed onto the reducer as a normal payload.data, not a promise.
Then, the container responsible for the rendering of the city.name is connected to the reducer managing the weather (so that you can access it using this.props) but, if the button is clicked, the console.log(this.props.tempo....) says that the object is undefined. Why?

[GitHub Repo link](https://github.com/Pangolino91/weather_test)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying your repo, logging to the console `this.props.tempo` works just fine for me in the render method of `ceciola` component.

Where I see the error, is in your `renderR()` function. You're attempting to use `diocane.city.name` but there is no 'city' property for that object.

Try: `<p>{diocane.name}</p>` to get the name.

_______ UPDATE ________

Response to your comment: I pulled the latest version from the repo, and again, everything seems to work just fine when you click the button to retrieve the data. As the code is now, you are doing:

`console.log(this.props.tempo[0])`

So, on first load of the component, you have nothing in the `props.tempo` array, so you see `undefined` in the console. When you click the button, you now have a single object in the array and that log statement works just fine.

I changed your `render()` method to:

```
render() {
    if (this.props.tempo.length > 0) {
      console.log("TEMPO", this.props.tempo[0])
      console.log("ID", this.props.tempo[0].id)
    }
    return (
        <div>
           {this.props.tempo.map(t => {
             return <div key={t.id}>{t.name}: {t.main.temp} </div>
           })}
        </div>
    );
}
```

And it logs out the expected information. You just need to confirm that the tempo prop has something in the array before attempting to access it. And then, when you do, make sure you're accessing the individual object(s) inside. I show an example of this in the `return()` method above: using `map` to iterate and return a new array of `<div>` elements with the tempo object info.

Comment: Hi! I updated the folder with the new commits. Now it's much clearer. Basically, in cecciola.js there is a console log for this.props.tempo. I can access that, but once I try to access the properties of tempo (base, cod, id, name, etc etc) it says that it is undefined. Why?